# Moving data between Cassandra JBOD folders manually

Tags: cassandra

General question:
Is it safe to move db files between table folders residing on different Cassandra JBOD folders (inside single node with Cassandra restart)?

Specific question:
I've configured backup on Cassandra cluster. Snapshots from every JBOD disk, schema and ring information stored on Amazon S3. And now I am considering possibility to recover cluster from scratch.

initial_tokens configuration property - makes node aware about tokens restored on this node. But do I need to somehow specify any information regarding how data is spread between JBOD folders? Or when startup Cassandra fetches bloom filters from every file and it does not matter on which JBOD folder this files are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its safe while the node is offline. Just turn node off, move files and start it back up.

You can take sstables from backups and put them on another cluster, what you have to worry about there is getting the token assignment to be the same. Otherwise the sstables you put on a node may not be the data that node is expected to hold (meaning reads wont go to it). An approach to this is described here: http://datascale.io/cloning-cassandra-clusters-fast-way/. You can copy the tokens from source cluster

```
nodetool ring | grep 0.0.0.0 | awk '{print $NF ", "}' | xargs | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed 's/,$//' | sed 's/^/initial_token: /' > /tmp/tokens.txt
```

and put that in the cassandra.yaml of corresponding node in destination cluster. While there set `auto_bootstrap: false`

This might change in future though if they start assigning token ranges to disks or something like that.